# chrome.experimental.socket API Crash Course?

Tags: javascript, sockets, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, websocket

I am trying to use the new 'chrome.experimental.socket' API calls in the recent Canary build and for the life of me I cannot figure it out. Does anyone have a sample script or something that they could throw up here to help me out? I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I've been watching the activity on the  pretty closely, and AFAIK the [chrome.experimental.socket API](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/experimental.socket.html) is still incomplete and actively in-progress as of Jan 16, 2011. It has partial UDP support and no TCP support yet. The main one working on this appears to be miket@chromium.org. You can watch his activity [here](http://code.google.com/u/103069702669776774675/updates).

Comment: Unfortunately google disabled the updates link for google code projects :-( http://code.google.com/p/support/issues/detail?id=24324 and https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-code-hosting/0XbdStxE_uw